# Is this code the right code for this task?

Tags: vb.net, function

Create a function called swapped that will take two integers(a,b) called byref and return a Boolean that is true if the numbers have been swapped.  Within the routine compare the numbers and if b>a swap them using a local variable temp, then return the value true else return the value false.

```
Function swapped(ByRef a As Boolean, ByRef b As Boolean)
    a = True
    b = True
    If b > a Then
        temp = b
        b = a
        a = temp
        a = True
        b = True
    Else
        a = False
        b = False
    End If
```

Comment: Appreciate you've made an attempt, but "take two integers" - do you see your first problem here?

Comment: (ByRef a As Integer, ByRef b As Integer) Is that what you think i should change it to?

Comment: I'd suggest that you should talk to your tutor/teacher about your confusion. They'll know what material they've taught you and be better placed to sort this out.

Answer (score 1):

First let's look at your code.

```
'The requirements called for 2 Integers, not Booleans.
'A Function requires a datatype, in this can a Boolean
Private Function swapped(ByRef a As Boolean, ByRef b As Boolean)
    'Assigning values here will overwrite the passed in values
    a = True
    b = True
    'What would it mean for True > True ??
    If b > a Then
        'temp isn't declared so this will not compile
        temp = b
        'here I think you are trying to do the swap
        'but all the values are True
        b = a
        a = temp
        a = True
        b = True
    Else
        a = False
        b = False

    End If
    'Function need a return value to match the datatype of the function
    'It is preceded by Return
End Function
```

If you are working in Visual Studio (free for the download), several of these errors will be highlighted for you.

Now, let's look at some code that may accomplish your task.

```
'Through comments you have already figured out that a and b are Integers
'In addition, Functions always need a return type. In this case a Boolean
    Function swapped(ByRef a As Integer, ByRef b As Integer) As Boolean
    'The values of a and b are passed to the function.
    'Keep the passed in value of a in a new variable
    If b > a Then
        Dim aPassedInValue = a
        'assign the value of b to a
        a = b
        'now assign the original value of a to b
        'we can't use a because we just changed the value of a in the above line
        b = aPassedInValue
        'There have been no errors so we can return True
        Return True
    Else 'We didn't swap them
        Return False
    End If
End Function

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim c As Integer = 7
    Dim d As Integer = 20
    MessageBox.Show($"c = {c}, d = {d}", "Before Swap")
    Dim ReturnValue = swapped(c, d)
    MessageBox.Show($"The return value of the swapped Function is {ReturnValue}")
    MessageBox.Show($"c = {c}, d = {d}", "After Swap")
End Sub
```

I think the point of this exercise is to demonstrate ByRef. You have changed the values in the function and the new values are reflected in the variable in the Button.Click Sub.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a fixed example. You should have the parameters declared as integers instead of boolean. The function itself should be declared as a boolean

```
Function swapped(ByRef a As Integer, ByRef b As Integer) As Boolean

    If b > a Then
       'Declare the temp variable
        Dim temp As Integer = b

       'Change b to a
        b = a
       'Set 'a' equal to the temp variable from the original b
        a = temp

        Return True

    Else
        Return False

    End If
End Function

Public Sub test()
    Dim intA As Integer
    Dim intB As Integer
    intA = 1
    intB = 2
    'Test b>a
    'Should return True
    Dim check As Boolean
    check = swapped(intA, intB)

    'Test Not(b>a)
    'Should return False
    Dim checkfalse As Boolean
    checkfalse = swapped(2, 2)
End Sub
```

Comment: A pre .NET syntax `functionName = resultValue` is used here in place of the .NET syntax `Return resultValue` to return a value from a function. Yes, it works, but it is typically not seen much anymore.

Comment: a is an Integer and b is an Integer. They cannot accept Boolean values.

Comment: @djv, yeah for some reason, I figured that they were using VBA to write their function. So, I just did it there. It took me back in time.

Comment: @Mary, that was a requirement in the description. _"Create a function called swapped that will take two integers(a,b)...."_ The function itself if supposed to return a **boolean** value.

Comment: Also there is no Variant type in vb.net. Yes, the requirement. But in your Else clause you try to set these Integer variables to Boolean values. That is a no, no. Especially when the calling code is still expecting Integers.

Comment: Oops, you are very right. That was a mistake. I will edit it. Thanks for pointing that out. I will edit it. Also, on the `variant`, I don't know why I was thinking that they were using VBA, but that's why I did it that way.

Answer (score 0):

Both existing answers do the trick. Here is one without a temp variable

```
Private Function swapped(ByRef a As Integer, ByRef b As Integer) As Boolean
    If b > a Then
        a = a + b
        b = a - b
        a = a - b
        Return True
    End If
    Return False
End Function

Sub Main()
    Dim a = 10
    Dim b = 11
    Console.WriteLine($"a: {a}, b: {b}")
    Console.WriteLine($"values were{If(swapped(a, b), " ", " not ")}swapped.")
    Console.WriteLine($"a: {a}, b: {b}")
    Console.ReadLine()
End Sub
```