# Im having problems figuring out how to print in an array

Tags: vb.net

Not sure how to output the numbers, once they are in ascending order.

This is the task in the pseudocode that I am trying to move into VB.

```
 Dim a() = {2,3,1,4}
 Dim swapped = False
 Output the values of a()
 Do Swapped  False
```

For I = 1 to end of the array Compare a(i-1) with a(i) if they are not in ascending order pass them to swapped (from task 1)
 Swapped(a(i-1),a(i)) assign the returned value to the 
     variable swapped.
     While swapped = True
     Output the values of a()

```vb
Dim num = New Integer() {2, 3, 1, 4}
Dim swapped As Boolean = False

While swapped = False
    For i = 1 To 4
        If num(i - 1) > num(i) Then
            temp = num(i)
            num(i) = num(i - 1)
            num(i - 1) = temp
            swapped = True
        Else
            swapped = False
        End If
    Next
End While
While swapped = True
    Console.WriteLine(num)
End While
Console.ReadLine()
```

Comment: I have read this a few times now, and I don't understand what you're asking. Can you provide a clearer description of the problem? Are you just trying to order the array in ascending order? Then it's simply `Dim a = {2,3,1,4}` `Dim b = a.OrderBy(Function(i) i).ToArray()` and to print, a simple foreach loop `For Each i In b` `Console.WriteLine(i)` `Next`

Comment: @djv It's supposed to be using the swap function from his previous question...that function is supposed to be incorporated into this question to basically create a bubble sort algorithm I think, and then output the sorted array

Comment: @soohoonigan just got back here after looking at the previous question... yeah I see that. The [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58613869/832052) adds a lot of missing context to this question.

Comment: In the second While, you never change the value of swapped in this While
        How will it end? It will either never run or never stop running.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
For Each n As Integer In num
    Console.WriteLine(n.ToString)
Next
```

Btw there's a problem with your swapping algorithm: if they are already in the right you will enter an infinite loop, and if there's a swap on the last number you'll exit the loop even if they are not in the right order. If it puzzles you let me a comment and we'll sort this out.

Answer (score 1):

Although, @laancelot showed you how to output the array, I thought I would show you a simple way to sort an array.

```
Private Sub OrderArray()
    Dim num As Integer() = {2, 3, 1, 4}
    Array.Sort(num)
    Console.WriteLine("Ascending")
    For Each i In num
        Console.WriteLine(i.ToString)
    Next
    'If you want it the other way around
    Array.Reverse(num)
    Console.WriteLine("Descending")
    For Each i In num
        Console.WriteLine(i.ToString)
    Next
    Console.ReadLine()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use vb net generic array order method, and you prefer use the swap concept, here you can try:

```
Private Sub TestOrderSwap()
    Dim num = New Integer() {9, 7, 0, 11, 12, 10, 6, 2, 3, 1, 4}
    If OrderSwap(num, "ASC") Then
        For a = 0 To num.Length - 1
            Debug.Print(num(a))
        Next
    End If
    If OrderSwap(num, "DESC") Then
        For a = 0 To num.Length - 1
            Debug.Print(num(a))
        Next
    End If
End Sub

Private Function OrderSwap(ByRef myArray As Integer(), OrderType As String) As Boolean
    Dim swp As Integer = 0
    Dim swpFlg As Boolean = False
    For a = 1 To myArray.Length - 1
        swp = myArray(a)
        For b = 0 To a - 1
            If (myArray(b) > swp And OrderType = "ASC") Or (myArray(b) < swp And OrderType = "DESC") Then
                For c = a - 1 To b Step -1
                    myArray(c + 1) = myArray(c)
                Next
                myArray(b) = swp
                swpFlg = True
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
    Next
    Return swpFlg
End Function
```